# Is there any pod or Library for handling Magento API calls in iOS

Tags: objective-c, magento, ios7, cocoapods

I want to handle API calls from Magento, I tried lognllc/LogNMagento. Its not satisfying my needs, So Please suggest anyother pod or Libraries for managing Magento API calls, for iOS 8. Thanks in advance.

```
-(BOOL)authenticationUsingUsername:(NSString *)username andPassword:(NSString *)password
{
    Magento.service.storeID = @1;

    [Magento.service renewSession];

    [Magento call:@[@"ios_core.login",@{
                    @"username" : username ,
                    @"password" : password}] success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
                            {
                                resultantData = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
                                resultantData = responseObject;
                            }
                    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) { isValid = NO;
                                NSLog(@"error %@", error.localizedDescription);
}];
```

Comment: please explain your needs

Comment: the parameters has to passed in the format of arrays in magento, but the logNMagento has a function called "CALL" I cannot convert it to the form of the array as required in the GET API Call using it using the "CALL" function.

Comment: in other words.. you don't know how to use the library from your code? please show us what you tried (your code).

Comment: i Have used the Library and i have send the call and i m getting the response too, but for that i have overidden the backend codes of magento according to the Parameters i can send on the call.

Comment: you have to help us understand your situation. for that, give as much info as possible. this includes code you use to call, explaining where and what is the problem, what you had to change in magento(if i got that right) to make it work.

Comment: @namerbenz can you please share the link from which you got the Magento iOS SDK?